# Error establishing a database connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I have a live site in Wordpress which is throwing the **Error establishing a database connection** on any page, but when I refresh the page, it starts working and the posts are returned from the database. I have also checked the error logs, I encounter the below kind of logs for many sql queries-

> WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM fap_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (56) ORDER BY meta_id ASC made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/fap/single-popular_searches.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/fap/header-search.php'), get_permalink, get_page_link, apply_filters('page_link'), call_user_func_array, custom_permalinks_page_link, get_post_meta, get_metadata, update_meta_cache

The parameters set for server are

```
Resource Limits max_execution_time  120
Resource Limits max_input_time      60
Resource Limits memory_limit        100M
```

I never get this error on dev site.Please share if you have found similar issue and what you done to resolve it?

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` say? Are you out of connections?

Comment: No, SHOW PROCESSLIST does not returns anything for connections.

Comment: Can you try to add define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M'); to your wp-config ? Have you big plugin installed ?

Comment: I have tried using define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M') but still the error is same..we have logs for database query interruption.